# ADODB reordset value extraction very slow

Tags: vba, performance, adodb, recordset

I load an sql table from server to excel to ADODB.recordset.
Then I want to populate my spreadsheet from that table.
I need the columns to be in a specific place, so I used the following code to do so.

```
Dim header As Range
Set header = sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, sh.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)

i = 1
Do Until rs.EOF
    For j = 1 To header.Columns.Count
        header.Cells(1, j).Offset(i, 0).Value = rs.Fields.item(header.Cells(1, j).Value)
    Next j
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Next s
```

The sheet gets populated, but it takes really long time. My table has 20 columns and 700 rows and the whole process takes minutes to finish.
I tried populating the sheet with a constant instead and the process finished after approx. one second. So I guess there is something wrong with the line

```
header.Cells(1, j).Offset(i, 0).Value = rs.Fields.item(header.Cells(1, j).Value)
```

Could anyone suggest, why my code runs so slow and how to improve the speed?

Comment: Have you turned off Screenupdating and set Calculation to manual? If you skip the write-to-sheet step how long does it take the loop to complete?  Writing ell-by-cell is slow, but "minutes" seems pretty long for this much data.

Comment: Wow the calculation to manual actually helped!! I tried to set the screenupdating to false before, but it did not help. Thank you very much. If you turn it into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you turned off Screenupdating and set Calculation to manual? Don't forget to reset at least Calculation when you're done (the ScreenUpdating setting does not persist past the end of your sub)

If you skip the write-to-sheet step how long does it take the loop to complete? 
Writing ell-by-cell is slow, but "minutes" seems pretty long for this much data